# Query sql in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the results of the previous query (`select Well_Dprod_Date,Formation_Name from data_dprod`).

```
 Well_Dprod_Date    Formation_Name  
 11/15/2002        BRF. 
 11/16/2002        BRF. 
 11/17/2002        BRF. 
 11/18/2002        BRF. 
 11/19/2002         BRF.    
 11/20/2002         BRF.    
 11/21/2002         BRF.    
 11/22/2002         BRF.    
 11/23/2002         BRF.
```

How do I get the results of the query is as follows :

```
 Well_Dprod_Date    Formation_Name  
 11/15/2002         BRF.        
 11/16/2002     
 11/17/2002     
 11/18/2002     
 11/19/2002     
 11/20/2002     
 11/21/2002     
 11/22/2002     
 11/23/2002          BRF.
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the logic behind the second result?

Comment: You need to explain the required logic - not the expected output. Do you need to list the Formation Name between two continious Well_Dprod_Dates? Is this a history of changes of Formation Name with the current value listed? etc

Comment: yes,I need the Formation_Name first and the last of the same Formation_Name between two continious Well_Dprod_Dates.

Comment: @bluefeet. I ask how can make the second query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little ambiguous.Is it what you want?

```
SELECT WELL_DPROD_DATE,
       FORMATION_NAME,
       CASE
         WHEN R1 = 1 OR R2 = 1 THEN
          FORMATION_NAME
         ELSE
          NULL
       END AS FORMATION_NAME_F
 FROM (SELECT WELL_DPROD_DATE,
           FORMATION_NAME,
           RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY FORMATION_NAME ORDER BY WELL_DPROD_DATE ASC) AS R1,
           RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY FORMATION_NAME ORDER BY WELL_DPROD_DATE DESC) AS R2
          FROM DATA_DPROD) T
```

Comment: Thank u very much, that's query working :)